# save_post not working with attachments

Tags: metabox, hooks, attachments, post-type

I've made a Meta Box for Posts and Pages, and while testing added Attachments too. But, curiously, the hook `save_post` does not fire.

```
$cpts = apply_filters( 'my_filter', array( 'post', 'page' ) ); // Added attachment through filter
foreach( $cpts as $pt )
{
    add_meta_box(
        'my_metabox_id',
        __( 'Meta Box' ), 
        array( $this, 'my_metabox_callback' ),
        $pt,
        'side'
    );
}
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_metabox_data' ) );
```

Why is that? Isn't `attachment` a Post Type too and hence subject to the same hooks as other post types?

Answer (score 4):

Not really, attachments are still not "full post types". [Manny Flerumond](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2234/manny-fleurmond) hints this quite well in [this thread](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Time-to-upgrade-WordPress-Media-td42327.html):

> Was thinking about this the past few days: currently any media files 
>   uploaded to a WordPress site defaults to the post status of `inherit`,
>   which is a holdover to when media attachments were just that.  Media
>   was  attached to a certain post, so it inherited the post's status. 
>   We are  starting to get away from attaching media directly to posts
>   now and are  even making them post like by allowing meta boxes and
>   taxonomies in recent  versions of WP.  I think a next logical step is
>   to give media post statuses  other than `inherit`.  I can think of a
>   number of cases where making an  image or file private could be
>   useful, among other things.

---

I've found the solution in this Stack Overflow post: [“save_post” hook not working on post type attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362066/). We have to use the hook [`edit_attachment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3875):

```
add_action( 'edit_attachment', array ( $this, 'save_attachment_mb_data'), 10, 1 );
public function save_attachment_mb_data( $post_id ) {
    // do_our_thing();
}
```

Note that it takes only one parameter, `$post_id`, so we cannot reuse the same callback as other post types. Well, unless we drop the second one (`$post_object`) for regular post types.

Comment: `edit_attachment` receives only the `$post_id` but the action `attachment_updated` (since 4.4.0) receives `$post_ID, $post_after, $post_before` and fires almost immediately after `edit_attachment`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_updated/

Comment: Very interesting, @Raba, can you post an answer with that info? I'd gladly test and change the selected answer.